# Create UIButton that responds while a Video is loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, uibutton, interrupt

I currently have a screen that loads a video through a method called `- loadCurrentVideo` and this method usually takes 2-3 seconds to complete while on wifi but 10-20 seconds to complete while on data.  I have a button built into the player that exits out of the player when it is tapped, but the button only works after the video is loaded.  I want to be able to add a button that exits out of the player whenever I tap it at any point during the loading and playing stages.

While the video is loading, I can't use any of the buttons on the player since i'm assuming the video is still loading and executing the method described above.  How can I build a button that is capable of always being available to respond to a tap and interrupts a method while it is executing to return to the previous screen that the app was on?

Below is the method:

```
- (void) loadCurrentVideo {
    __block UIActivityIndicatorView *pw = _pleaseWait;
    __block KolorEyes *ke = _koloreyes;
    __block UISlider *slider = _timeSlider;

    _pleaseWait.hidden = NO;
    [_pleaseWait startAnimating];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        [_koloreyes setDisplayDevice:kKE_DISPLAY_HMD forView:_viewRectHandle];
        [_koloreyes setCameraControlMode:kKE_CAMERA_TOUCH forView:_viewRectHandle];
        err = [_koloreyes setAssetURL:url1
                withCompletionHandler:^{
                    NSLog(@"Video %@", url1.path);
                    [pw stopAnimating];
                    pw.hidden = YES;

                    CMTime duration = [ke getMediaDuration];
                    if (CMTIME_IS_INDEFINITE(duration)) {
                        slider.hidden = YES;
                    }
                    else {
                        [slider setMaximumValue:CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)];
                    }

                    [ke play];
                    [self postView];
                    Log("Kolor Eyes set asset URL completion handler");
                }];
        if (err != kKE_ERR_NONE) {
            [pw stopAnimating];
            pw.hidden = YES;
            Log("Kolor Eyes setAssetURL failed with error %d", err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your loadCurrentVideo method is synchronous, you need to make it asynchronous or run it in a background thread.

Comment: @DonaldTrumpatemyhamster i've added the code for my method, is this the correct way to make it asynchronous

Comment: Its async but you are using the main thread. Run it on a background thread, all UI elements need the main thread.

Comment: If you do as R3D3vil says and run the whole thing in a background thread then it will crash unless you run the [pw startAnimating] and [pw stopAnimating] in the main thread (as they are gui elements, you can't run a gui element from the background thread).

Comment: @SausageMagnificationUnit is there anything else I need to do on the main thread to prevent it from crashing?  I removed the calls as you suggested and it still crashes